# how to extend background color on column layouts css

Tags: html, css

I seem to be having trouble to extend my background color for my 2 column layout. The user can add categories so the background color has to be able to adjust with the amount of categories the user wants to add in.

[image]

html file:

```
 {% for category in categories %}
    <div class="row__2 sub-pages--background">
      <div class="sub-pages--categories-background">
        <div class="sub-pages--categories">
            <a href="{% url 'blogging_logs:topics' category.id %}" class="sub-pages--categories-position ">{{ category }}
              <img  class="sub-pages--img" src="{{ category.category_image.url }}">
            </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  {% empty %}
    <p>No categories entered yet.</p>
  {% endfor %}
```

css file:

```
&--background {
  background-color: $mainBackground;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}
```

I feel like it has to do with the way I'm formatting my divs

Comment: Are you using `float` in there?

Comment: I use float:Left in my row__2 class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you mentioned in comments that you are using floats, simply add a parent element that will have the background and then add something known as [clearfix](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_clearfix.asp), at the end of it.

HTML:

```
<div class="parent--background">
 {% for category in categories %}
    <div class="row__2 sub-pages--background">
      <div class="sub-pages--categories-background">
        <div class="sub-pages--categories">
            <a href="{% url 'blogging_logs:topics' category.id %}" class="sub-pages--categories-position ">{{ category }}
              <img  class="sub-pages--img" src="{{ category.category_image.url }}">
            </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  {% empty %}
    <p>No categories entered yet.</p>
  {% endfor %}
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.clearfix::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
```